# Scheduling expression

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedule

Scheduling expression is 0 0 7 * * ? which means: run every day (weekdays +weekends) each month each year at 7AM
but when scheduled job is created the settings are the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ignore what this screen says ;-) Just go back (don't try to save) check the next run and you will see it will be next day at 07:00